# Why should the shebang line always be the first line?

Tags: perl, unix, solaris, shebang

I have a simple perl script as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "hello world!\n";
```

I can execute this script as below:

```
>temp.pl
hello world!
>
```

If I add some comments like this:

```
#this script is just for test
#the shebang
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "hello world!\n";
```

and when I try to execute, it gives me output as below:

```
> temp.pl
use: Command not found.
use: Command not found.
print: Command not found.
>
```

The point here is the shebang line should be always at the top, no matter what.
Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The shebang must be the first line because it is interpreted by the **kernel**, which looks at the two bytes at the start of an executable file. If these are `#!` the rest of the line is interpreted as the executable to run and with the script file available to that program. (Details vary slightly, but that is the picture).

Since the kernel will only look at the first two characters and has no notion of further lines, you must place the hash bang in line 1.

Now what happens if the kernel can't execute a file beginning with `#!whatever`? The shell, attempting to fork an executable and being informed by the kernel that it can't execute the program, as a last resort attempts to interpret the file contents as a shell script. Since the shell is not perl, you get a bunch of errors, exactly the same as if you attempted to run

```
 sh temp.pl
```

Comment: On a historical note, there was at least one flavor of Unix (forget which one) that used the full 4-character sequence `#! /` (hash, bang, space, slash) for detecting scripts.

Comment: Everybody keeps telling that. But it is false. Name it or it didn't happen :-)

Comment: **DYNIX**!  It was in the autoconf "portable shell" documentation.  However, it seems that this documentation was changed/corrected in 2009 (my work with autoconf was from the late 1990's).  http://web.archive.org/web/20080118164924/http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.57/html_chapter/autoconf_10.html  (So id **did** happen!  It just **didn't** happen any more. ;-)

Comment: As I understand it, it was only in the documentation, but the kernel code looked just at the first two characters like any other Unix kernel. Until proven wrong we can assume any `#!interpreter` would be understood by any Unix ever produced.

Comment: @Jens As mentioned in my answer, ExtUtils::MakeMaker, Perl's module installer, has special code to deal with Unixen which did not understand `#!interpreter`. This was in turn taken from "Programming Perl" first edition p274 from 1991. At this point you'd have to ask Larry Wall for what systems he found it necessary, but that's some pretty strong evidence that `#!interpreter` was not always reliable. However, it is now.

Comment: @Jens I also discovered that Perl [tests whether `#!foo` or `#! foo` works](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/blead/Configure#L1461) added in 1994. I can't find exactly what systems this was done for, but they put in a lot of work. The Unix world used to be a whole lot woolier. Reading through Perl's Configure is a delightful trip through the many layers of cross-platform hell over the decades.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks for providing this info about perl. Still, to this day, nobody actually found a kernel source file where the `exec*()` implementation required the space. While I am inclined to believe it never existed, some believe it was there and became extinct. In the absence of fossils, Occam's Razor appears to support my stance, no? :-)

Comment: @Jens I'd be inclined to think there's a lot of old commercial Unix source out there that never saw the light of the Internet.  Perl's pretty pragmatic, it worked on some crazy broken environments, and they put a lot of work into it.  If you're really curious you could send Larry an email, he's a nice guy.

Comment: No, the script is not passed on the interpreter's stdin (if it were the script would be able to read from stdin) but as an argument (and on some systems also as `argv[0]`). Exception to that are setuid/setgid scripts on some systems where the interpreter is passed a `/dev/fd/x` argument where the script is open for reading on fd x. More info at http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/

Answer (score 8):

It's not just that it has to be the first line, the characters `#!` have to be the first two bytes in the file.  That this can run scripts is a shell feature, not an OS one, and it's not specific to any particular scripting language.

When the system is told to execute the contents of a file, either with something like `.../path/to/bin/program`, or via the analogous route through the PATH, it examines the first few bytes of the file to look for the 'magic numbers' which reveal what type of file it is (you can peek at that process using the file(1) command).  If it's a compiled binary, then it'll load and execute it in an appropriate manner, and if those first two bytes are `#!` it'll do the 'shebang-hack'.

The 'shebang-hack' is a special case that's employed by some shells (in fact, essentially every one, but it's convention rather than a requirement), in which the shell reads the remaining bytes up to a newline, interprets these as a filename, and then executes that file giving it the rest of the current file as input.  Plus some details you can probably read about [elsewhere](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-16.html).

*Some* (versions of) shells will allow quite long first lines, some allow only short ones; some allow multiple arguments, some allow only one.

If the file doesn't start with `#!`, but does appear to be text, some shells will heuristically try to execute it anyway.  Csh (if I recall correctly) takes a punt on it being a csh-script, and there's some complicated and arcane case to do with some shells' behaviour if the first line is blank, which life is too short to remember.

There are interesting and extensive details (and accurate ones, in the sense that they match my recollections!) at [Sven Mascheck's #! page](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/).

Comment: +1 for an excellent and interesting answer. Perhaps you should mention that this applies only to Unix-like systems?

Comment: It is not a shell feature, it is an OS feature.

Comment: @jlliagre : well, yes and no. It's a feature that has migrated from shells to the kernel over time. At present, calls like execve(1) are documented as being able to handle this, but historically, it was the shell which was responsible for catching the failure of the kernel to execute the script as a binary; also different shells (sh, csh, ksh, ...) behave slightly differently. Thus where the magic _actually_ happens, in any particular case, is probably subtly OS- and shell-dependent.

Comment: Granted it used to be sometimes handled by shells in the last century. This was only required for the default interpreter (sh on AT&T Unix, csh on some BSDs) when the kernel wasn't handling the shebang itself. Nowadays, all Unix / Unix like kernels are implementing the feature. I believe ksh and bash no more parse the first line for a shebang. zsh and perl are doing it. In any case, this parsing is redundant when the script is executable and called as such like in sarathi example.

Comment: @jilliagre. It is still handled by some shells. For instance, Some Unices don't support scripts as script interpreters and some shells (like `zsh`) will still fall back to interpret the she-bang line themselves.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the explanations above, which are covered in detail [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-16.html) and [here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) there's some special things about the `#!` and Perl which haven't been mentioned yet.

Perl reads the `#!` line and does two things.  First, if the path doesn't look like perl, it will rexecute the program using that!  For example...

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello world!"
```

Will run correctly if executed as `perl /path/to/that/program`.  I don't know for what historical reason Perl does this, but it comes in handy when you're testing multiple languages with Test::Harness.

The second thing is Perl finds any switches in the `#!` line and applies them just as if they were on the command line.  This is why `#!/usr/bin/perl -w` works to turn on warnings.

It's worth mentioning that unlike the other parts of the shebang processing, this is all done inside Perl, not Unix, and so is portable to Windows.

Another Perl + shebang note is this madness you might find at the top of many Perl programs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -w -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if 0; # not running under some shell
```

Sometimes, on very, very, very old systems, `#!` does not work and the Perl program is executed by the shell.  The `eval` forces the the shell to first thing rexecute the file with Perl.  Since shell statements end on newline it doesn't see the `if 0`.  Perl does see the `if 0`, so it doesn't execute the eval.  Both Perl and shell have syntactically equivalent `eval` operators which makes the hack work.

Comment: You shouldn't reference other answers as *above* or *below*.

Comment: It's the royal above.  Please turn your monitor upside down to fix the problem.

Comment: I think the reason for the first oddball behavior is that if you have a system where shebang doesn't work, but you can configure a single interpreter for *all* scripts, you can configure that interpreter to be `perl`, and then your system will act like one where shebang works. :)

Comment: Comments must always go *above* the shebang line.

Answer (score 0):

At least on POSIX compliant systems, the shebang is used to tell the executable loader what to do with text files having the executable bit set.

The loader knows what to do with binary files, they start with a "magic number", usually ELF related these days.

On the other hand, text files that do not have a shebang are executed by the POSIX compliant shell available on the machine, this is why you have these shell error messages:

```
use: Command not found.
use: Command not found.
print: Command not found.
```

When your executable is not to be interpreted by the POSIX compliant shell, you need to tell the loader what interpreter to use. Other OSes like Windows pick the file extension to figure it out but Unix doesn't use or care about extensions in this specific case. What it uses is the shebang on the first line which states what command interpreter to use. The only drawback is that the scripting language should ignore this first line. This is hopefully the case as `#` is a comment line prefix with most scripting languages.

Despite popular belief, portable scripts should not have a shebang at all. In particular `#!/bin/sh` is not recommended for them.