# standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, minikube

I am building the Dockerfile for python script which will run in minikube windows 10 system below is my Dockerfile

Building the docker using the below command
`docker build -t python-helloworld .`

and loading that in minikube docker demon
`docker save python-helloworld | (eval $(minikube docker-env) && docker load)`

Docker File

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
#add user group and ass user to that group
RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup

#creates work dir   
WORKDIR /app

#copy python script to the container folder app
COPY helloworld.py /app/helloworld.py

#user is appuser
USER appuser

ENTRYPOINT  ["python", "/app/helloworld.py"]
```

pythoncronjob.yml file (cron job file)

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: python-helloworld
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 5
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: python-helloworld
            image: python-helloworld
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command: [/app/helloworld.py]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Below is the command to run this Kubernetes job
`kubectl create -f pythoncronjob.yml`

But getting the below  error job is not running scuessfully but when u ran the Dockerfile alone its work fine

standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494853/standard-init-linux-go178-exec-user-process-caused-exec-format-error

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I can see that you add the command `command: [/app/helloworld.py]` to yaml file.

so you need to (in Dockerfile):

```
RUN chmod +x /app/helloworld.py
```

set shebang to your `py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python # whatever your defualt python to run the script
```

or setup the command the same as you did in `Dockerfile`

Comment: Thanks @LinPy. I forget this frequently and you're always here to answer. :-)

Comment: I had the same problem trying to run a docker in SageMaker environment. This solution perfectly worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 190):

This can also happen when your host machine has a different architecture from your guest container image.

E.g. running an arm container on a host with x86-64 architecture

Comment: In my case, I was running x86-64 architecture on Raspberry Pi. Had to change the base image to ARM

Comment: I was wondering why my docker build fails on CI runner. Thanks!

Comment: I got the same thing building on an M1 mac with docker preview for Apple Silicon.  My solution was to build on a different device.

Comment: @Caleb Now, that's not really a *solution*, is it? More like a workaround.

Comment: That's crazy, this is the main selling point of containerization, docker etc.

Comment: Oof I wouldn't have thought of that. Damn you M1 processor!

Comment: Switch a kubernetes cluster node type, without paying attention to the fact that the arch was different 

Comment: @mawburn I know that feel

Comment: You can also add the platform to build for in the first line: `FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 python:3.7-alpine`. This way you build it on the M1 and can run the container on Linux machines.

Comment: I got the same error running a node:latest image in an armv7l (32-bit) machine with docker 19. After I tried a lot of stuff, Finally, I used node:16 (instead of node:lates) and it worked! So, try using an older image, and it may work.

Answer (score 54):

You probably compile your docker image for the wrong platform.

For instance, if you run on arm64 (Apple M1 or M2?) and want to compile to run on intel/amd, you shall use the --platform option of docker build.

```bash
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t registry.gitlab.com/group/project:1.0-amd64 ./
```

If you use `docker-compose.yml` to build your image, use:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build: 
      context: ./myapp
      ...
```

For the docker platform naming list, and more info, you should read: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/

tip: to build for multiple platforms, use `--platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64`

Comment: If you build images in Apple and use them on Linux host machines then you better specify the platform when building them

Comment: Thanks, defo an issue on M1! I spent the whole day playing around with different `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` combos but it was this thing in the end

Comment: I had the same problem, but was able to build my images using GitHub Actions, where selected platform matches the final one - so it worked.

Answer (score 43):

I recently encountered the problem when running a logstash container

*standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"*

Noticed that the shebang line (#!/bin/sh) on the entrypoint.sh was typed in the second line instead of the first line of the entrypoint.sh file.

When the shebang line is made as to the first line in the script, the error went away and ***"docker run -it logstashimage:latest sh"*** worked perfectly.

Comment: Omg it took me almost an hour and I hadn't realized that. Thanks!

Comment: Further explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910744/why-should-the-shebang-line-always-be-the-first-line

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue recently. Sharing my experience here. Basically I was trying to run a `ARM` docker image on `X86_64` architecture.

Here is the steps I have followed

1. Check host architecture

   ```
    uname -m # Display the host architecture
    #x86_64

    docker pull arm32v7/ubuntu # Get ARM docker image

    docker run --rm -t arm32v7/ubuntu uname -m
    standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
   ```
2. Setting up ARM emulation on x86

Using [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/) allows us to to build ARM  binaries on x86 machine without needing a cross compiler.

```
sudo apt-get install qemu binfmt-support qemu-user-static # Install the qemu packages
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes # This step will execute the registering scripts
```

3. Run the docker image

   ```
   $ docker run --rm -t arm32v7/ubuntu uname -m
   armv7l
   ```

Reference : [Building ARM container on x86](https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/docker/building-arm-container-on-x86/)

Answer (score 11):

[Rufus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3177701/rufus) is correct, I came across this issue when attempting to build a x86 server image on my M1 MacBook which is arm64.

I was able to build for the correct target architecture by adding the "platform" attribute to my docker-compose.yml.

```yaml
services:
    web:
        image: myimage/web:latest
        platform: linux/x86_64
        build:
            context: ./myfolder
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
```

Comment: This solved my issue with docker compose, however note that it only worked with the newer `docker compose` vs. `docker-compose`. The new `docker compose` is a drop in replacement and I had no issues doing just that.

Comment: You just saved my life. After 1.5 days of pulling my hair out as to why my new Mac can't spin up the same AWS ECS container using exactly the same code as my old Mac, and after getting no error logs from AWS. This, after pulling an error log from the Celery container on my AWS instance via SSH that gave a me new Google search term to use that ultimately led me to this page and your comment, was the answer. I thank you :).

Answer (score 7):

Another two reasons could raise this issue if you run docker on **Windows**:

- scripts line endings are not LF (linux)
- scripts encoding should be utf-8 + BOM

Answer (score -1):

I met exactly the same error message. It was fixed by install qemu on the host machine. No idea about the reason.