# standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "permission denied"

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, kubernetes-ingress

When trying to run gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend as non root, the pod goes to crashLoopBackOff state when I see the below error in logs

**standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "permission denied"**

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: ingress-default-backend
  name: ingress-default-backend
  namespace: ingress-haproxy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: ingress-default-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: ingress-default-backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ingress-default-backend
          image: gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend:1.0
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          securityContext:
            runAsGroup: 1000
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1000
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

**Note: This issue persist only with ubuntu 18.04.1**

Comment: Hi, how was Your cluster deployed and which k8s version do You have?

Comment: I have deployed 1.15 cluster on AWS ec2 host(ubuntu 18.04.1).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the issue is caused by lack of executable permissions to the user that You are trying to run this containers as in Your deployment.

You can try to modify the image dockerfile and add few lines that would allow the right user to execute commands like in this [github](https://github.com/fsanys/sonarqube-developer/issues/1) issue.

There is also lots of useful information about this in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58298774/standard-init-linux-go211-exec-user-process-caused-exec-format-error) StackOverflow post.

Hope it Helps.

Answer (score -2):

try notes these,the privilege is error,becasue securityContext
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM6QF.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).