# Obtain credentials to an ECS with IAM role

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-secrets-manager

trying to test a way to obtain creds to an ECS task without hard-coded creds by using IAM role

created a dummy python app that retrive the  secret and returns it,example :

```
{
username: "x",
password: "x",
engine: "postgres",
host: "x",
port: 5432,
dbInstanceIdentifier: "x"
}
```

Dockerfile (asked to be added)

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY app2.py .
RUN chmod +x /app/app2.py
CMD [ "python3", "/app/app2.py"]
```

**ERROR i get :**

each task fails instantly,when i ssh the task ec2 and logs the container :

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Created a task definition and used the correct Task role

```
Task role
devops-TestRole
```

IAM role (AWS Service: ecs-tasks):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
```

And

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:x:x:secret:x",
                "arn:aws:kms:x:x:key/x"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

THANKS !!

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile you used to build the image?

Comment: sure ! ill add it to me question.Just to be clear,it works locally when adding a volume to me ~/.aws/credentials folder

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

As mentioned here
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69273104/15648070),It can be caused due different chips(using arm64-M1)

Used

```
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t devops-tests .
```

And it fixed it !