# docker run not working: no container created despite making container image

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, containers, boot

## Summary

`docker run` doesn't seem to build a container (but it also doesn't throw an error) despite `docker build` successfully building the container image.

## Input and Output

***1. Successful docker image creation..***

```
$ docker build -t minitwitter:latest .
...
Successfully built da191988e0db
Successfully tagged minitwitter:latest
```

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY    TAG         IMAGE ID        CREATED         SIZE
minitwitter   latest      da191988e0db    6 seconds ago   173MB
python        3.7-alpine  b11d2a09763f    9 days ago      98.8MB
```

***2. ..and docker run completes without error..***

```
$ docker run --name minitwitter -d -p 8000:5000 --rm minitwitter:latest
e8835f1b4c72c8e1a8736589c74d56ee2d12ec7bcfb4695531759fb1c2cf0e48
```

***3. ..but docker container doesn't seem to exist.***

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE  COMMAND  CREATED  STATUS  PORTS  NAMES
```

And navigating to the port where the app should be exposed, http://localhost:8000, returns the connection error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

## Docker file, boot.sh

The Dockerfile and boot.sh files are pretty simple I think:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN adduser -D minitwitter

WORKDIR /home/minitwitter

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m venv env
RUN env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN env/bin/pip install gunicorn

COPY app app
COPY migrations migrations
COPY minitwitter.py config.py boot.sh ./
RUN chmod a+x boot.sh

ENV FLASK_APP minitwitter.py

RUN chown -R minitwitter:minitwitter ./
USER minitwitter

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

**boot.sh**

```
# BOOTS A DOCKER CONTAINER
#!/bin/sh
source env/bin/activate
flask db upgrade
exec gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - minitwitter:app
```

Comment: You may want to try running it `docker run --interactive --tty ....` rather than detached to more easily view the logs and any exceptions. Alternatively, `docker container ls --all` should show the exited container too. You can then `docker container logs [CONTAINER-ID]` to see what happened.

Comment: Customarily I'd `source /env/bin/activate` after creating the virtualenv and *before* `pip --requirements` etc. Could you not fold most of the `boot.sh` into your `Dockerfile` and have the `ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn","-b",":5000",....]`

Comment: @DazWilkin `docker container ls --all` shows no containers. That suggests to me that a container simply isn't being created. Do you agree? What'd you recommend given this additional fact?

Comment: Correct. It appears the container is not being created (correctly).

Comment: Hmmm.... although you have `docker run ... --rm ...` too which removes completed containers. Drop that too.

Comment: Aha! Okay I removed the `--rm` arg and, perhaps as you expected, the container shows up. That is, it seems the container is created and lives for 2 seconds before exiting.

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
7dd1d493a1e4        minitwitter:latest   "./boot.sh"         41 seconds ago      Exited (1) 39 seconds ago                       minitwitter`

Comment: This helped narrow the problem space -- thank you!

Do you have a recommendation on how to further identify what's causing it to be so short-lived?

Comment: What do you get from `docker container logs 7dd`? (**NB** you can use any uniquely identifying subset of the container ID)

Comment: My working theory is that, by activating the virtualenv *afterwards*, you're borking it. I think you should activate the virtualenv before the pip install etc.

Comment: @DazWilkin Placing the shebang (`#!/bin/sh`) in the _first_ line of `boot.sh` solved it for me (I've documented this in the Answer below).

Comment: The log was: `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"`. I investigated that error and ultimately found the answer listed below.

Answer (score 1):

Place the 'shebang' -- `#!/bin/sh` -- on the *first line* of the `boot.sh` shell script.

How I found this answer: [This blog post](https://www.lewuathe.com/exec-format-error-in-docker-container.html) which refers to this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910744/why-should-the-shebang-line-always-be-the-first-line).

The problem: the original script has a comment on the first line and the shebang on the second line.

Note: The title of the 'Question' is misleading: a docker container *was built*. The container, however, was short-lived and given I used the `-rm` option in the `docker run` command, the container was deleted after it terminated within 2 seconds; this is why it didn't appear in the `docker images -a` command.